# Algorithm for items placement

Tags: algorithm, logic, tooltip

I have a "complex" problem where I have a bunch of tooltips (orange) on top of elements (black) that can be randomly placed on screen. The tooltips are a big square with a triangle in the middle of one of it's 4 sides pointing though the element direction. By default, the triangle will be in the middle of the element, but can be moved as long as it stay close to it, so we can't easily understand it refer to this element and not another one.

The problem is, the tooltip must NOT overlap each other, and can't be out of screen.

[Image of my tooltip problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhLOs.jpg)

I thought about first placing every tooltips to their default position (triangle pointing down), and then check if they are out of screen or overlap another one, and if so, try another position. But using this technique (which is probably the simplest one), I do not guarantee the best placement since once a tooltip has been placed, I will not replace him if another one can't fit anywhere otherwise it become too complex.

Does someone have any tips/idea how to deal with this type of problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an instance of the map labelling problem. Wikipedia has [an article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_label_placement).

Comment: Thanks! Another related post for reference:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833695/bubble-chart-label-placement-algorithm-preferably-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You could place all the tooltips using some sort of physical simulation of repulsive electrical charges, similar to what is done in some [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing) for drawing graphs. You could model each tooltip as an object attached with a soft spring to its black box, while simulating a strong repulsive force between all the tooltips and between a tooltip and the edge of the image. You calculate all the forces and move the tooltips iteratively, until all positions converge. You could play with making the force scale as inverse square, inverse cube, etc to find nice results.

This might be a bit of work to implement, but should probably give decent results for simple cases. It is probably impossible to guarantee that a good solution always exists, since if you add too many tooltips, your image will be full.